# How do I create a feature dataframe with shape of [244, 14], similar to that of the initial dataframe using tqdm?

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

Below is what i have tried:

```
rows=[]
for _, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(),total=df.shape[0]):
    row_data=dict(
        week_of_year=row.date.week,
                month=row.date.month,
                    NGTC=row.NGTC,
                    NGRRO=row.NGRRO,
                    CSP=row.CSP,
                    NGMP=row.NGMP,
                    NGPI=row.NGPI,
                    NGUSV=row.NGUSV,
                    HOSP=row.HOSP,
                    HDD=row.HDD,
                    CDD=row.CDD,
                    NGSP=row.NGSP,
                    pre_NGSP=row.pre_NGSP,
            change_NGSP=row.change_NGSP)
    
rows.append(row_data)
```

After I tried the above code, I discovered that my `features_df.shape` is `[1,14]`, instead of `[244,14]`. How do I resolve this problem please?

Comment: The indentation of `rows.append(row_data)` is wrong: Move it inside the `for`-loop. Now it only `append`s the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote wrong indent at `rows.append(row_data)`, it's not in loop, so you only got the last row in rows.

```
rows=[]
    for _, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(),total=df.shape[0]):
        row_data=dict(
            week_of_year=row.date.week,
                   month=row.date.month,
                     NGTC=row.NGTC,
                     NGRRO=row.NGRRO,
                     CSP=row.CSP,
                     NGMP=row.NGMP,
                     NGPI=row.NGPI,
                     NGUSV=row.NGUSV,
                     HOSP=row.HOSP,
                     HDD=row.HDD,
                     CDD=row.CDD,
                     NGSP=row.NGSP,
                     pre_NGSP=row.pre_NGSP,
                change_NGSP=row.change_NGSP)
    
        rows.append(row_data).
```